# Must use import to load ES Module: /Users/*path/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/objectWithoutPropertiesLoose.js require() of ES modules is not supported

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, babeljs, server-side-rendering

I am trying to use Server-side-rendering in create-react-application but i have been getting the following error.
I have tried to update the babel version and change the type : 'commonjs' in package.json but is of no use.

This is the link i have been refering to implement ssr in my project link [A hands-on guide for a Server-Side Rendering React app](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/a-hands-on-guide-for-a-server-side-rendering-react-app-dd1efa3ec0d8)

```
Must use import to load ES Module:/Users/*path/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/objectWithoutPropertiesLoose.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of /Users/*path/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/objectWithoutPropertiesLoose.js from /Users/Rajat/Desktop/ebullientech_ssr_example/ebullientech_io_reactjs/node_modules/react-spring/renderprops.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename objectWithoutPropertiesLoose.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from /Users/*path/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/package.json.
```

My server.js file is as follows

```
require("@babel/register")({
  presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
  plugins: [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    [
      "transform-assets",
      {
        extensions: ["css", "svg", "png"],
        name: "static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]",
      },
    ],
  ],
});
const React = require("react");
const ReactDOMServer = require("react-dom/server");
const App = require("../src/App").default;
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");


const app = express();

app.get("/*", (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(`Request URL = ${req.url}`);
  if (req.url !== "/") {
    return next();
  }
  const reactApp = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(React.createElement(App));
  console.log(reactApp);

  const indexFile = path.resolve("build/index.html");
  fs.readFile(indexFile, "utf8", (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      const errMsg = `There is an error: ${err}`;
      console.error(errMsg);
      return res.status(500).send(errMsg);
    }

    return res.send(
      data.replace('<div id="root"></div>', `<div id="root">${reactApp}</div>`)
    );
  });
});

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "../build")));

app.listen(8080, () =>
  console.log("Express server is running on localhost:8080")
);
```

My Package.json file is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.28",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.9",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "@types/babel-types": "^7.0.9",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-assets": "^1.0.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "concurrently": "^5.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "fontawesome": "^5.6.3",
    "jquery": "^3.5.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.6",
    "package.json": "^2.0.1",
    "popper": "^1.0.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-google-recaptcha": "^2.0.1",
    "react-google-recaptcha-v3": "^1.5.1",
    "react-helmet": "^6.0.0",
    "react-owl-carousel": "^2.3.1",
    "react-recaptcha-v3": "^1.1.0",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-sitemap": "^1.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.3",
    "react-spring": "^8.0.27",
    "react-visibility-sensor": "^5.1.1",
    "reactstrap": "^8.4.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.1.0",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "sitemap": "babel-node ./src/Sitemap_files/sitemap.js",
    "predeploy": "npm run sitemap",
    "nodemon": "nodemon ./server/index.cjs"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.11.6",
    "@babel/node": "^7.10.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/register": "^7.12.10",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-assets": "^1.0.2",
    "generate-robotstxt": "^8.0.3"
  }
}
```

I get a different error if i try to serve the server.js without nodemon i.e:

```
/Users/*path/src/App.js:1
import React from 'react';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1054:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1102:27)
    at Module._compile (/Users/Rajat/Desktop/ebullientech_ssr_example/ebullientech_io_reactjs/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:99:24)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (/Users/Rajat/Desktop/ebullientech_ssr_example/ebullientech_io_reactjs/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:104:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Rajat/Desktop/ebullientech_ssr_example/ebullientech_io_reactjs/server/index.cjs:16:13)
```

Any Help would be appreciated..Thankyou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. Please do add the following plugin "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties" using npm or yarn and refer to it in the babel/register configuration settings. Like so:

```
require('@babel/register')({
    ignore: [/(node_module)/],
    presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
        {
            "transform-assets",
            {
              "extensions": [
                "css",
                "svg"
              ],
              "name": "static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]"
            }
          }
      ]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `"type": "module"` to your `package.json`.

Comment: Hello @kuka0len ..This is the error that poped up after "ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental"

Comment: You should probably upgrade your Node.js

Comment: I did that...still nothing